# Python lxml write dom object into a file

Tags: python, dom, lxml

I have the following code to parse an html file and manipulate DOM with lxml. When I am done I need to write the dom object into a file. Can you please suggest the syntax?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import html5lib

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8").read(), "html5lib")
dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
xpath_id = "somepath"
dom.xpath(f'//*[@id="{xpath_id}"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[7]/a[2]')[0].text = "Hello"
print(dom.xpath(f'//*[@id="{xpath_id}"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[7]/a[2]')[0].text)
>>>Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I used lxml's own parser to make a tree object, which has xpath attribute, as follows:

```
from lxml import etree
filename = "old.html"
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(filename, parser)
...use tree.xpath to manipulate dom
result = etree.tostring(tree.getroot(),pretty_print=True, method="html")
with open("new.html", "wb") as f:
 f.write(result)
```